# Could not scrape the URL because it was rate limited

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

Since several days ago when I use Facebook's Sharing Debugger scrape my company's page, it returns:

***Rate Limit Reached
Could not scrape the URL because it was rate limited.***

It seems that my website is blocked by Facebook but I couldn't find any solution on the Web. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to contact Facebook support and ask them to unlock.

Before continuing with scrapping, make sure you understand the limits. Check this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting